# Unable to fetch a valid error code when AWS Cognito authentication fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, http-status-code-401

I am using AWS Cognito for Authentication using user pools and I have all my APIs configured on the API gateway. I directly hit cognito from the Angular client, store the tokens returned by Cognito in local storage and use them in subsequent calls.

The problem however is, if the token I send from Angular has expired the Cognito authentication fails and no Integration backend is hit in this case. As a result, I am getting a 401 error in Chrome.

The interesting thing however is that this 401 code is not available to me in the HTTP response object that is passed to Angular. A default 0 code is received by the Angular and this seems to be the case with all the error code received from server (either cognito or backend).

I tried to explore around and found that the issue might be because the gateway is not sending proper CORS headers in the error cases. I have read following related docs but unfortunately I couldn't find out a way to resolve the issue.

Can someone suggest a solution to this.

Edit: I also read somewhere that it is a known AWS issue. Is that the case ?

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the Cognito session before making the call to the API Gateway.

In the example below, the `getSession` method has a callback that prints out any error messages to the console, and returns.

```js
////// Cognito.js
import {
  CognitoUserPool,
  CookieStorage
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

import config from '../config'

const cookieSettings = {
  domain: '.xxxxxxxxxxx.com',
  secure: true
}

export default {
  cookieSettings,
  pool: new CognitoUserPool({
    UserPoolId: config.UserPoolId,
    ClientId: config.ClientId,
    Storage: new CookieStorage(cookieSettings)
  })
}
//////

////// actions.js
import Cognito from './Cognito'

export function fetchUser() {

  // get cognito user cookies
  const cognitoUser = Cognito.pool.getCurrentUser()
  if (cognitoUser != null) {
    // try to get session from cognito
    cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)

        return;
      }

      fetch('https://api-gateway-url', { 
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + session.getAccessToken().getJwtToken(), 
        }
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => console.log(json))
    })
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried this already. However, my getSession() always seems to return a null value. Even though my app works fine and I am able to make various API calls, still the getSession() return null. Any ideas?

Comment: Cognito needs to have a reference to the storage of the credentials. So if you are storing it to Local Storage manually, getSession() might not be able to get to it. Try to use `CookieStorage` as I've done above. If it doesn't work, please post the code you are trying.